# <SpringProperty> is always undefined and default value does not work

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback

I have springproperty:

```
<springProperty scope="context" name="logUrl" source="logging.logstashHost" resource="application-unittest.yml"
                    defaultValue="myUrl:39290"/>
```

in my `logback-test.xml`

and use it like:

```
  <appender name="myAppender" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender">
        <destination>${logUrl}</destination>
        <keepAliveDuration>5 minutes</keepAliveDuration>
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
            <providers>
            </providers>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
```

However this ${logUrl} is always undefined:

> logUrl_IS_UNDEFINED':

Why isnt spring picking up the property? And why isnt defaultValue used? I tried to rename my `logback-test.xml` to `logback-test-spring.xml` or `logback-spring.xml` but my tests arent picking the configuration then.

What is the way to fix it?

Comment: Did you get the solution of this please? I am also facing similar issue with logstash-encoder.